# работа с Enum в С #

Tags: c#

Проблема с пониманием `Enum` — не могу разобраться, как искать в зубчатом массиве и как сравнивать в зубчатом массиве данные, применяя `Enum`. Если Вам не сложно, покажите или объясните, как для тупого.
Вот то, что есть:

```
    class Program
{
    // 1) declare enum ComputerType
    enum ComputersType
    {
        Desktop = 0,
        Laptop = 1,
        Server = 2,
    }
    // 2) declare struct Computer
    struct Computer
    {
        public ComputersType comp;
        public int CPU;
        public float HGz;
        public int memory;
        public int HDD;

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // 3) declare jagged array of computers size 4 (4 departments)
        var departmentComputers = new Computer[4][];

        // 4) set the size of every array in jagged array (number of computers)
        departmentComputers[0] = new Computer[5];
        departmentComputers[1] = new Computer[3];
        departmentComputers[2] = new Computer[5];
        departmentComputers[3] = new Computer[4];

        // 5) initialize array
        // Note: use loops and if-else statements
        Computer Desktop = new Computer();
        {
            Desktop.comp = ComputersType.Desktop;
            Desktop.CPU = 2;
            Desktop.HGz = 1.6F;
            Desktop.memory = 4;
            Desktop.HDD = 200;
        }

        Computer Laptop = new Computer();
        {
            Laptop.comp = ComputersType.Laptop;
            Laptop.CPU = 2;
            Laptop.HGz = 1.6F;
            Laptop.memory = 4;
            Laptop.HDD = 200;
        }
        Computer Server = new Computer();
        {
            Server.comp = ComputersType.Server;
            Server.CPU = 2;
            Server.HGz = 1.6F;
            Server.memory = 4;
            Server.HDD = 200;
        }
        departmentComputers[0][0] = Desktop;

        Computer[] department;
        int computerIndex;
        department = departmentComputers[0];
        computerIndex = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            department[computerIndex++] = Desktop;
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            department[computerIndex++] = Laptop;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            department[computerIndex++] = Server;

        department = departmentComputers[1];
        computerIndex = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            department[computerIndex++] = Laptop;

        department = departmentComputers[2];
        computerIndex = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            department[computerIndex++] = Desktop;
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            department[computerIndex++] = Laptop;

        department = departmentComputers[3];
        computerIndex = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            department[computerIndex++] = Desktop;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            department[computerIndex++] = Laptop;
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            department[computerIndex++] = Server;
        // 6) count total number of every type of computers

        // 7) count total number of all computers
        // Note: use loops and if-else statements
        // Note: use the same loop for 6) and 7)

            for (var x = 0; x < department.GetLength(x); x++)
            {
                for (var y = 0; y < department.GetLength(y); y++)
                {
                     for (int k = 0; k < departmentComputers[x][y]; k++)
```

А дальше я сижу второй день и ничего не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю, зачем ты ищешь только в одном `department = departmentComputers[3];`

```
 foreach (var i1 in department)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i1);
            Console.WriteLine(i1.comp);
            Console.WriteLine(i1.CPU);
            Console.WriteLine(i1.HDD);
            Console.WriteLine(i1.HGz);
            Console.WriteLine(i1.memory);
        }
```

Вот так будет искать по всем

```
var c = new Computer[][] { departmentComputers[0], departmentComputers[1], departmentComputers[2], departmentComputers[3] };

        foreach (var i1 in c)
        {


            foreach (var i2 in i1)
            {
                if (i2.comp == ComputersType.Server)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server ============================");
                }
                else { Console.WriteLine("?============================="); }

                //Так можешь использовать номер enum
                Console.WriteLine("ComputersType=" + i2.comp + "=" + (int)i2.comp);
                //Console.WriteLine(i2);
                Console.WriteLine(i2.comp);
                Console.WriteLine(i2.CPU);
                Console.WriteLine(i2.HDD);
                Console.WriteLine(i2.HGz);
                Console.WriteLine(i2.memory);               


            }
        }
```

Comment: это не поиск, это объявление массива:
department = departmentComputers[3];
вопрос:: как используя  Enum, struct, зубчатый массив, икать данные и манипулировать этими данными.

Comment: обычными способами. приведи что-то конкретное, конкретные действия с какими-либо значениями.  Мне не известно для чего тебе enum и как ты собрался его использовать.

Comment: Enum, это условие задания, то что надо выполнить.. в примере отмечено как //1) и так далее до //7). Я выполнить задания с 1 по 5, а вот на 6,7 не могу выполнить хотя вроде как они легкие!